# Оптимизация кода тенниса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу проверить верный ли счет в теннисе.
  В теннисе `сет` заканчивается, когда один из игроков выигрывает 6 игр, а другой выигрывает меньше 5 или, если оба игрока выиграют как минимум 5 игр и пока один из игроков не выиграет 7 игр.
 Надо определить попал ли в функцию правильный счет.

```js
console.log(tennis(3, 6))//надо true
console.log(tennis(8, 5))//тут false
console.log(tennis(6, 5))//и тут false

function tennis(score1,score2){
    if(score1 == 7 && score2 == 5|| score1 == 5 && score2 == 7){
     return true;
    }if(score1 == 7 &&score2 == 6 || score1== 6 && score2 == 7){
       return true;
    }
    if(score1 == 6 && score2 < 5||score1 <5 && score2 == 6){
      return true;}if(score1== 6&&score2 ==6){
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути можно проверять выигрышный результат для 6 и 7 для одного из счетов и при этом проверять соответствует ли условию второй счет.

Вот так:

```
// если один из счетов равен 6(выигрышный счет), 
// то проверить второй счет. В данном случае надо проверить на < 5
if (score1 == 6) return score2 < 5
if (score2 == 6) return score1 < 5
```

Но этот код должен быть под следующим кодом чтобы для счета 6 и 7 или 7 и 6 выдавало правильный результат.

Для 7 немного посложнее, надо проверить что другой счет больше 5 и меньше 7. Счета 7 и 7 не может быть, кто первый набрал 7, тот и выиграл.

```
if (score1 == 7) return score2 >= 5 && score2 < 7
if (score2 == 7) return score1 >= 5 && score1 < 7
```

Код `if (score1== 6 && score2 == 6) {` вроде вообще не имеет смысла, Вы писали:

> или если оба игрока выиграют как минимум 5 игр и пока один из игроков
>   не выиграет 7 игр.

тот и тот набарали больше 5 но никто не набрал 7, поэтому надо false.

Вот полный код:

```js
console.log(tennis(3, 6))//надо true
console.log(tennis(8, 5))//тут false
console.log(tennis(6, 5))//и тут false

function tennis (score1, score2) {
    if (score1 == 7) return score2 >= 5 && score2 < 7
    if (score2 == 7) return score1 >= 5 && score1 < 7
    if (score1 == 6) return score2 < 5
    if (score2 == 6) return score1 < 5
    
    return false
}
```

Можно решить еще круче если использовать `Math.min` и `Math.max` чтобы определить меньший и больший счет, не нужно будет делать столько проверок:

```js
console.log(tennis(3, 6))//надо true
console.log(tennis(8, 5))//тут false
console.log(tennis(6, 5))//и тут false

function tennis (a, b) {
    const max = Math.max(a, b)
    const min = Math.min(a, b)

    return (max == 6 && min < 5) ||
        (max == 7 && min != 7 && min >= 5)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, вышло красиво.